# Can a string and int comparison be ever True in python2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, comparison-operators

I know python2.7 allows comparison between different types. So the equality comparison between str and int will result in `False`.  Can the comparison ever be true depending on the values of a and b?

```
a = input('we input some string value a')
if (a==int('some string b')):
    print("yes")
else:
    print("no, never!!")
```

Can this above snippet ever output "yes"? If yes, when?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:** Yes, this can produce `yes` as an answer (assuming `'some string b'` is a placeholder for a string that might actually contain a legal `int` representation; if it's that exact literal string, you'd just get a `ValueError` when you called `int` on it).

**Long answer**:

1. An `int` and a `str` will *never* compare equal. `int` and `str` are unrelated different types, and while there is a *tiny* amount of type flexibility (different numeric types are comparable the way they are in most languages), even on Python 2 (where `<`/`>`/`<=`/`>=` don't raise exceptions and use a ridiculous fallback comparison to provide an arbitrary ordering of unrelated types) it's a strongly typed language and `int` and `str` do not interoperate like that.
2. That said, `input` on Python 2 is *terrible*; it `eval`s the text received from the user, so if the user enters `12345`, it will in fact return an `int`. So if the user input a legal `int` literal, and `'some string b'` was itself a legal representation of an `int`, then you'd've provided a real `int` to compare to on both sides, and this code could return `yes`, not because `str` and `int` compare equal to one another, but because `input` will return `int`s when the input looks like an `int` (and `float`s for `float`-looking things).

---

Side-note: In pathological cases, someone could have name-shadowed the `input` and/or `int` built-ins on a prior line, and anything could happen. I'm not going to get into the details there; it's a programming language, you're allowed to do stupid things with it, but there's nothing interesting about telling it to do stupid things and wondering if it will be stupid.